# Consuming RESTful web services in Unity3d, cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'string'... how to convert or work around?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to consuming RESTful web services in Unity3d using Unity Engine Networking API. Following this video https://youtu.be/TrOLTrIX9Yk?t=289
But i'm getting "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' to 'string'"
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCR1X.png

Trying to "Consuming RESTful web services in Unity3d and learn how to use the Unity Engine Networking API" using my own Rest Api following this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrOLTrIX9Yk at this point in the video https://youtu.be/TrOLTrIX9Yk?t=289 I got lost

Tried seeing if it was my Unity version so I downloaded 2018.1.1f1 (which Dilmer was using in his video) same Error occurred.

```
//RestClient.cs

using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.Networking;

public class RestClient : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static RestClient _instance;

    public static RestClient Instance 
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = FindObjectOfType<RestClient>();
                if (_instance == null)
                {
                    GameObject go = new GameObject();
                    go.name = typeof(RestClient).Name;
                    _instance = go.AddComponent<RestClient>();
                    DontDestroyOnLoad(go);
                }
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable Get(string url)
    {
        using (UnityWebRequest www = UnityWebRequest.Get(url))
        {

            yield return www.SendWebRequest();

            if (www.isNetworkError)
            {
                Debug.Log(www.error);
            }
            else
            {
                if (www.isDone)
                {
                    string jsonResult = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(www.downloadHandler.data);
                    Debug.Log(jsonResult);
                }
            }

        }
    }


}
```

```
//Game_URL.cs

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Game_URL : MonoBehaviour
{
    public string WEB_URL = "";

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(RestClient.Instance.Get(WEB_URL));
    }

}
```

Expected actual result getting console output of my MeshData simular to:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/r2eyq.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcDQi.png

Comment: This was caused by the typo of "IEnumerable" instead of "IEnumerator". Problems caused by typographical errors are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for stack overflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error you're getting is misleading because your IDE is assuming you're trying to invoke another overload of `StartCoroutine` that takes a method name (a string) as its first argument.

Your actual issue is that `StartCoroutine` expects an `IEnumerator`, not an `IEnumerable`. Change the return type of your `Get` method to `IEnumerator` (as it is in the video) and it should work.

Comment: Good eye spotting the typo there

Comment: Thank you, I didnt even realize I was using IEnumerable and not IEnumerator... your one of a kind thank you kindly @Klaycon